# how to make image gallery easier

Tags: javascript

I know how to make the image gallery using javascript .. when I click on an image it gets bigger ... OK so if I have 50 images ... I must write 50 functions for my gallery to work !! ... 
my question is ... Is there a way of writing a short function that will save me both time and afford?

for example this is one of the functions :

```
function changeImg1(){
  $("#show").hide("explode");
  $("#show").show("bounce");
  $("#captionText").hide("explode");
  $("#captionText").show("pulsate");
  showImage.setAttribute("src",images[1]);
  showCaption.innerHTML=(captions[1]);
  imageIndex=1;
  captionIndex=1;
};
```

Thanks a lot guys I learned a lot from you ...

Answer (score 0):

you need to read about "this" in js, and jquery. for example

```
$(".many_many_img_with_same_class").click(function(){

  var current_img_src = $(this).attr( "src" );

  alert(current_img_src);

});
```

so than you click img, function run in context of this img, and always show src of clicked img.
p.s. for anower question in comment

html

```
<img src="/some/place1" data-any-spec-text="my text 1" class="many_many_img_with_same_class">
<img src="/some/place124" data-any-spec-text="my text 222" class="many_many_img_with_same_class">
<img src="/some/other/place" data-any-spec-text="more text 222" class="many_many_img_with_same_class">
```

js

```
$(".many_many_img_with_same_class").click(function(){

  var current_img_src = $(this).attr( "src" );
  var current_img_capton_info = $(this).data( "any-spec-text" );

  alert(current_img_src, current_img_capton_info);

});
```

Comment: @deathdragon dont' forget to add jquery

Comment: yes it worked ... thanks a lot man ...... but I have another thing ... what if I want to add a caption under every image ... and the caption changes with the image automatically ... do I use the same function or what ? ... Oh I have the captions in an array inside a var in the javascript itself ... I hope my question is clear enough ...

Comment: you can add caption info direcly to image usig "data" attribute. <img src="someplace" data-my-awesome-text="any caption text">. and get this data through $(this).data("my-awesome-text") just like you take src in my answer

Comment: you are the best internet man I have ever seen ... thanks a million ... i hope all your days are joyful and cheerful ...